# Cannot get Windows 7 connect to samba without issues

Tags: windows-7, samba

I've a problem with Windows 7 Samba/Ubuntu Server connectivity.

When I first start the Windows machine, I can map the network drive without issues.
But after a while of inactivity it disconnects and almost all the time gives me error when reconnecting. After that the only way to get back the connection is to disconnect map, restart windows and it will automatically work again!

It's driving me nuts.

From ubuntu laptop this never happens, I simply browser workgroup share from networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have had similar experience. It also remains unsolved for me. It is either related to network connectivity (that might drop and thanks to bugs in Windows - trying to reconnect in a failing manner) or issues in the block of the OS that is responsible for the underlying part.

However, one workaround is to tunnel your **SMB** daemon port via **SSH**. Not only is that going to provide encryption, but it will also solve your stability problem (at least it did for me). Take a look at [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier). It is one piece of mature software. What I do is tunnel a port to my **SMB** server (*a Client-to-Server* rule) - this way the connection remains pretty much static (**TCP/IP**) and disconnects are handled automatically. This enables me to bind a port on the localhost Windows machine, that i can use to map a network drive with - so, a pair of **127.0.0.1** and **445**. Once accessed - the traffic is tunneled and arrives at the remote endpoint. That's it.

But, as with everything, there are particular caveats. The real problem, is that **port 445** is already bound on localhost by the OS and the bad news is - it is not possible to unbind it the easy way. Also, it is **NOT** possible to map a network drive to any other port but **445** (let's leave out **139/NetBIOS** out of this).

So, what I really do, is actually bind this port on my router (thanks to **dd-wrt**) and just map the **IP** of my router for a network drive. This way I can circumvent the limitations outlined above.

Another workaround, OS wise, is using a "bruteforce" method to free up the bound port. Inspect **ncpa.cpl** and navigate to your adapters properties. You would have to sacrifice a service - **File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks**: remove/uninstall it. Then, download [this](http://www.sshvpn.de) utility. What it does is apply a series of registry changes to deliberately force the OS to free up the needed port. Once everything is done - you can now bind **445** on localhost through **Tunnelier** or some **netsh** goodness. Good luck!